# How to allow user to tweet their message on web view?

Tags: android, twitter, dialog

I am doing Twitter post. its working fine. it directly tweet the message which i set in the twitter_text.

```
try {
    TwitterUtils.sendTweet(prefs, twitter_text);
    mTwitterHandler.post(mUpdateTwitterNotification);
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

I want to show the dialog like face book in which user can modify their tweet.

so, How to get the Twitter dialogue view after authorisation, before publishing a tweet in android ?

Comment: You will need to design your own custom dialog for that with a EditText and in onClick of positve button you will need to get the text from EditText and pass it as twitter_text to your above code.

Answer (score 0):

do some changes as shown below:  1) For **PrepareRequestTokenActivity** Activity make changes as in do in background method as

```
            @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Uri...params) {
        final Uri uri = params[0];
        final String oauth_verifier = uri.getQueryParameter(OAuth.OAUTH_VERIFIER);

        try {
            provider.retrieveAccessToken(consumer, oauth_verifier);

            final Editor edit = prefs.edit();
            edit.putString(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN, consumer.getToken());
            edit.putString(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET, consumer.getTokenSecret());
            edit.commit();

            String token = prefs.getString(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN, "");
            String secret = prefs.getString(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET, "");


            //
            context.startActivity(new Intent(context,twitter.class));
            //executeAfterAccessTokenRetrieval();


            Log.i(TAG, "OAuth - Access Token Retrieved");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "OAuth - Access Token Retrieval Error", e);
        }

        return null;
    }
```

i have used **twitter.class** as main class for twitter in twitter class my code is as shown below

```
     import oauth.signpost.OAuth;

 import android.app.Activity;

 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.content.SharedPreferences;
 import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
 import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.os.Handler;
 import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.EditText;
 import android.widget.TextView;
 import android.widget.Toast;

    public class twitter extends Activity{
private SharedPreferences prefs;
private final Handler mTwitterHandler = new Handler();
EditText et_sharedata;
Button bt_post,bt_login;
TextView loginstatus,tv_heading;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tw);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    this.prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    loginstatus=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_twloginstatus);
    et_sharedata=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_twdata);
    tv_heading= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_heading);
    tv_heading.setSelected(true);
    if(TwitterUtils.isAuthenticated(prefs))
    {

    }else{
        Intent i = new Intent(twitter.this, PrepareRequestTokenActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

}

public void onClick(View v){
    switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.bt_twshare:{
         String s_spin_text = et_sharedata.getText().toString();

            try {
                TwitterUtils.sendTweet(prefs,s_spin_text);
                //TwitterUtils.sendTweet(prefs,getTweetMsg());
                mTwitterHandler.post(mUpdateTwitterNotification);
                twitter.this.finish();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();

            } 

    }break;
    case R.id.iv_back:
        twitter.this.finish();
        break;
    case R.id.iv_index:
        startActivity(new Intent(this,home.class));
        break;

    }
}
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    updateLoginStatus();
}
public void updateLoginStatus() {
    if(TwitterUtils.isAuthenticated(prefs))
    {
        loginstatus.setText("You Are Logged In Twitter");
    }else{
        loginstatus.setText("You Are Not Logged In Twitter");
    }
}
private void clearCredentials() {
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    final Editor edit = prefs.edit();
    edit.remove(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN);
    edit.remove(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET);
    edit.commit();
}
final Runnable mUpdateTwitterNotification = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Tweet sent !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
  };
  }
```

and my **tw.xml** is as shown below

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:background="@drawable/mainbg"
       android:layout_gravity="center"
       android:orientation="vertical" >
    <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/top_strip"
     >

     <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_back"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:src="@drawable/back" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_heading"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
        android:text="Increase Your Brain Power"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:maxWidth="220dp" 
        android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"  
        android:singleLine="true" 
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="20px"
        />

     <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_index"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:src="@drawable/index" />
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" >

 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_twloginstatus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="46dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#000000" />

     <Button
        android:id="@+id/bt_twshare"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
         android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="onClick"
       android:background="@drawable/post_data"/>
</RelativeLayout>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et_twdata"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.37" 
    android:maxLength="140"
     android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
     android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="140dp"
    android:gravity="top">"


</EditText>

 </LinearLayout>
```